# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server-VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I got an error while using VS2017, the information is strange.
Also i have searched and tried others' solution, but doesn't work.
Anyone have the same issue?

[image]

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html You might try to run Jexus Manager (add the VS solution file as a new IIS Express server) and let Visual Studio Project Diagnostics tell what's wrong.